# If $\sin\alpha + \cos\alpha = 0.2$, find the numerical value of $\sin2\alpha$.

Tags: trigonometry

> If $\sin\alpha + \cos\alpha = 0.2$, find the numerical value of $\sin2\alpha$. How do I find a value for $\sin\alpha$ or $\cos\alpha$ so I can use a double angle formula?

I know how to solve a problem like

"*If $\cos\alpha = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ , find $\sin2\alpha$*"

by using the 'double angle' formula: $\sin2\alpha = 2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha$ like this:

Start by computing $\sin\alpha$
$$\sin^2\alpha = 1 -\cos^2\alpha = 1-(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})^2 = \frac{1}{4}$$
so
$$\sin\alpha = \pm\frac{1}{2}$$
then it's just a simple matter of plugging $\sin\alpha = \pm\frac{1}{2}$ and $\cos\alpha=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ into $$\sin2\alpha = 2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha$$  to get $$\sin2\alpha = \pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$

Where I can not make progress with the question

"If $\sin\alpha + \cos\alpha = 0.2$, find the numerical value of $\sin2\alpha$".

Is how do I find a value for $\sin\alpha$ or $\cos\alpha$ so I can use a double angle formula?

What I have tried:

If $\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha = 0.2$
then $\sin\alpha=0.2-\cos\alpha$
and $\cos\alpha=0.2-\sin\alpha$. Should I start by  by computing $\sin\alpha$ using
$\sin^2\alpha = 1 -\cos^2\alpha = 1-(0.2-\cos\alpha)^2$?

Comment: $2 \sin\alpha = 0.4 - 2 \cos \alpha$, and $\sin^2 \alpha + \cos^2 \alpha = 1$. Two equations, two variables.

Comment: Do you really mean $2 \sin \alpha$?  Because you give many indications that you are looking for $\sin 2\alpha$ instead.  Are you aware that these are different quantities?

Comment: You are quite correct. I did mean $\sin2\alpha$. I will edit the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also know that $\sin^2 \alpha + \cos^2 \alpha=1$, so square what you are given, getting $\sin^2 \alpha + 2 \sin \alpha \cos \alpha + \cos^2 \alpha = 0.04, 2 \sin \alpha \cos \alpha=-0.96=\sin (2\alpha)$

Comment: I understand how you got the value of $\sin2\alpha$ (that's what even I thought of doing). The question however asks for the *minimum* value of $\sin2\alpha$. Is that *minimum* redundant? Because, doing this way, we reach only *one* answer.

Comment: Squaring goes one way but not the other.  There can't be any other answers.  With this argument, we have not shown that this value works-it might be spuriously introduced by the squaring.  But you can observe that $\sin 0 + \cos 0 =1, \sin( -\frac \pi2) + \cos( -\frac \pi2)=-1$ and the mean value theorem to argue there must be a solution.

Comment: @RossMillikan. No. Squaring will give extraneous values for $\sin \alpha$ and $\cos \alpha$, but, you have definitely proved that, if $\sin\alpha + \cos\alpha = 0.2$, then $\sin  2\alpha = -0.96$. In the other direction, $\sin  2\alpha = -0.96$ implies $\sin\alpha + \cos\alpha = \pm 0.2$ which has nothing to do with the original problem.

Answer (score 6):

We have 
$$s^2=(\cos\alpha+\sin\alpha)^2=1+2\cos\alpha\sin\alpha=(0.2)^2$$
so we find
$$p=\sin\alpha\cos\alpha=-0.48$$
hence $\sin\alpha$ and $\cos\alpha$ are roots of the quadratic equation:
$$x^2-sx+p=x^2-0.2x-0.48=0$$

Answer (score 4):

$$\cos \alpha + \sin \alpha = \sqrt{2} (\frac{\cos \alpha}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{\sin \alpha}{\sqrt{2}}) = \sqrt{2}(\sin \frac{\pi}{4} \cos\alpha +  \cos \frac{\pi}{4} \sin \alpha) 
= \sqrt{2}\sin(\frac{\pi}{4} + \alpha) = .2 $$

Taking the inverse sin of each side yields
$$ \alpha = 2.2143 + 2 \pi n_1 \mid n_1 \in \mathbb{Z} \,\,\,\text{or}\,\,\, \alpha = 2\pi n_2 - .643501 \mid n_2 \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: Hint:  If you precede your trig functions with backslashes, they come out in the correct font.  So \cos gives $\cos$ instead of $cos$ and so on.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin\alpha + \cos\alpha = 0.2$$

$$\sin\alpha + \sqrt {1-\sin^2\alpha}= 0.2$$

$$\sqrt{1-\sin^2\alpha}= 0.2-\sin\alpha$$

$$1-\sin^2\alpha=0.04-0.4\sin\alpha+\sin^2\alpha$$

$$2\sin^2\alpha-0.4\sin\alpha-0.96=0$$

$$\sin^2\alpha-0.2\sin\alpha-0.48=0$$

$$\sin\alpha=\frac{0.2\pm1.392...}{2}$$

$$2\sin\alpha=1,592...$$
$$2\sin\alpha=-1,192...$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $$\sin { \alpha  } +\cos { \alpha  } =0.2,\quad \quad (1)\\ \sin { \alpha  } -\cos { \alpha  } =x,\quad\ \quad (2)$$

Sum up $(1)$ and $(2)$: $$2\sin { \alpha  } =0.2+x$$
Multiply $(1)$ and $(2)$:$$2\sin ^{ 2 }{ \alpha  } -1=0.2x$$

Answer (score 0):

If $\sin\alpha + \cos\alpha = 0.2$, then squaring both sides and simplifying will produce $2 \sin \alpha \cos \alpha = -0.96$.

It follows that $\sin^2 \alpha - 2 \sin(\alpha) \cos(\alpha) + \cos^2 \alpha = 1.96$, from which we conclude $\sin\alpha - \cos\alpha = \pm 1.4$

From
$\left\{
    \begin{array}{l}
      \sin\alpha + \cos\alpha = 0.2\\
      \sin\alpha - \cos\alpha = 1.4
    \end{array}
\right \}$
we find $(\sin \alpha, \cos \alpha) = (0.8, -0.6)$

From
$\left\{
    \begin{array}{l}
      \sin\alpha + \cos\alpha = 0.2\\
      \sin\alpha - \cos\alpha = -1.4
    \end{array}
\right \}$
we find $(\sin \alpha, \cos \alpha) = (-0.6, 0.8)$

Note that neither of these solutions is extraneous.

Answer (score -1):

\begin{align}
  \sin \alpha+\cos \alpha &= 0.2 \\
  (\sin \alpha+\cos \alpha)^2 &= 0.04 \\
  \sin^2 \alpha + \cos^2 \alpha + 2\sin \alpha \cos\alpha &= 0.04 \\
  1+\sin 2\alpha &= 0.04 \\
  \sin 2\alpha &= -0.96
\end{align}

and that would be straight forward to proceed